# RecyclerView - callback when view is no longer visible

Tags: android, listener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView with its Adapter and LayoutManager. Adapter has approximate 15 different ViewHolders. One of them contain WebView which loads external contents (99% of them are videos outside of YouTube).
The problem comes when any View of Adapter gets out of the screen - video in WebView keeps playing and sound is playing. Still, that's acceptable for me.

The key problem starts when I move to another Activity. The sound of the video is still present.

Is there any way RecyclerView could notify me when any of its children views change visibility state (meaning disappears from display)?

Comment: RecyclerView.RecyclerListener ? or not directly by RecyclerView.OnScrollListener ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Gonna respond to myself. Best approach is add `RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener` to my RecyclerView and then handle events with my WebView when `onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view)` is called.

Example:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            if (webView != null) {
                webView.onResume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

            if (webView != null) {
                webView.onPause();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this method causes the webview to play the video before the webview becomes fully visible as a view attaching itself to the recyclerview is different to a view being fully visible in a recyclerview.

Comment: Just a note: If you are within the adapter you can overwrite _onViewDetachedFromWindow()_ directly. This is awesome.

Comment: This is just awesome. Thankyou so much!

Comment: How can I get position of item attached/detached from window?

Comment: If you do what Plexus above mentioned you will have the view holder and can just do holder.getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Works like a charm.
also the solution given by @plexus works perfect

Answer (score 5):

One approach you may be able to use is the following:

You can use the `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();` and `layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();` to get the first and last positions that are visible on the screen. If your item does not fall between these values, then it is off the screen.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for, or if you need/want to use another approach for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is probably using a `RecyclerListener` - see the documentation available: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecyclerListener.html

The callback gets `onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)` so you can easily tell which views are recycled.

Comment: problem with onViewRecycled is that items in the recycle view are not necessarily recycled when they are out of view, depends a lot on how much cache you have put on the recycle view as well