# Recyclerview: callback for view when fully visible

Tags: android, listener, android-recyclerview

This is the use case:

I have a recyclerview list of 5 food stuff imageviews:

1. Watermelon
2. Mango
3. Peach
4. Apple
5. Guava

I want to log an output `(Log.e(TAG, "Peach shown!")` when the peach imageview is fully visiile in the recyclerview when the user scroll past it.

Is there a callback that is called when a view is **fully visible** in the recyclerview? I almost want to turn the method `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition ()` into a callback method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

I read this thread: 
[RecyclerView - callback when view is no longer visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683811/recyclerview-callback-when-view-is-no-longer-visible) and looked at the docs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener.html but I see the callback method  `onChildViewAttachedToWindow()` is called when:

> Called when a view is attached to the RecyclerView.

Attached can be before the view actually gets displayed.

I can think of one highly inefficient way of doing this:

1. Set the `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` on your recyclerview
2. Call `mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` inside the `onScrolled` method. Check the int that is returned to equal 3.

Each time the recyclerview scrolls, hundreds of calculations are going to be performed.

Comment: Maybe toWindow() is not same as toRecyclerview.

Comment: @Simon: how did you solve this problem? Just call it once?

Answer (score 4):

You actually should handle it in the `onScrolled()` method, as you mentioned. The `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` method is very efficient and the calculations being made will not affect most devices, including the low-end ones.

As a side note, I think what you want is the `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` method.

Been there, done that :-)

Comment: OK.let me try that later today.

Comment: I tried this method but it calls the log a few times when it scrolls pass the peach imageview. I just want it to be called once. Do you know how I can make it call once only?

Comment: There are several patterns for that, depending on what you want to achieve. Basically, you need to trigger a "lock condition" after getting the right CompletelyVisibleItem and then reset it on some other condition (change in list element count, getting to the end of the list, exiting the Activity/Fragment). But again, this is very implementation-specific and I can not give you a single solution without knowing what your exact goal is :-)

Comment: I used RxJava in order to make it trigger once. Create an observable that registers a scroll listener, gets the first and last visible position on each scroll, returns a position range. use `scan()` to keep track of the current and previous range. Then finally, check if your target is in the current range, but not the previous one. `take(1)` of those and it will complete and clean up after the first match.