# How can a view track if it is visible on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, view

Is it possible for a view to **track** when it is visible and when it is no longer visible on the screen? The keyword here is **track** as opposed to “check”. In effect I am looking for something that behaves like `onShowingOnScreen` and `onStopShowingOnScreen`.

For some background, my view is nested quite a bit: `Activity => ViewPager => Fragment => RecyclerView.Adapter => CatViewHolder => myView`.

If you care: For the sake of this question, let’s assume this particular CatViewHolder is used only once while some other DogViewHolder is what gets reused multiple time.

Also, if the view cannot do this, can the ViewHolder do it? (It's effectively the same result).

**update**

For completeness, imagine I have to attach a slab to the window when the `myView` is visible and detach that slab from the window the moment `myView` stops being visible. ( I use slab so as not to use the word View again).

Comment: Try this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31684283/1478764

Comment: Thanks for the link. Assuming I cannot change the constructor of the adapter. How do I get a pointer to the RecyclerView either from inside the adapter or from inside the ViewHolder?

Answer (score 1):

First, the view must be attached to the current view hierarchy.  So you'll need to register a [OnAttachStateChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnAttachStateChangeListener.html) with [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnAttachStateChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener%29) on the view to see if it even *could* be visible.

You can then call [getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame%28android.graphics.Rect%29) to find out Android has allocated any display space to it.

Comment: This answer is quite promising so thank you very dearly (+1). Really thank you. But a few problems arise. There is a ViewPager in the hierarchy. Hence, the attached will be called about three pages away and the detached will be called about three pages away: whereas I need to perform the action at the precise moment the user is on the page displaying  **myView** or away from the page displaying **myView**. The dead-band presents a bit of a problem.

Comment: You can choose the moment that getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame is called, from the main thread.  It just won't give you the value you want if you do it while the view is not attached.